# Mapping int to Boolean

Tags: java, dozer

Can Dozer(v. 5.3.2) map an int type to a Boolean(Wrapper) type?

Answer (score 3):

From a cursory reading of the documentation, you can map pretty much anything to anything via a custom `BeanMapping`, so... "yes"

Comment: But, Is it posible an automatic conversion with the same rules that C language?

Comment: Yes - you would have to write something simple like `return i != 0`

Answer (score 1):

Yes....you can map int type to Boolean or any other data type. For this kind of mapping you need [Custom Converters](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
    public class NewDozerConverter 
    extends DozerConverter<Integer, Boolean> {

  public NewDozerConverter() {
    super(Integer.class, Boolean.class);
  }

  public Boolean convertTo(Integer source, Boolean destination) {
    if (source > 1) {
      return Boolean.TRUE;
    } else if (source < 0) {
      return Boolean.FALSE;
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown value!");
  }

  public Integer convertFrom(Boolean source, Integer destination) {
    if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(source)) {
      return 1;
    } else if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(source)) {
      return 0;
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown value!");
  }

}
```

Comment: `convertTo(Integer source, Boolean destination)` should consider the case where source Integer is equal to 1 or 0. Updated code:

`
public Boolean convertTo(Integer source, Boolean destination) {
    if (source >= 1) {
      return Boolean.TRUE;
    } else if (source <= 0) {
      return Boolean.FALSE;
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown value!");
  }
`

Comment: This code is riddled with errors. :) First, 'source' may be null in both functions.  Second, convertTo(...) throws an exception for either of the two values returned by convertFrom(...)!  That is, convertTo(convertFrom(Boolean.TRUE, null)) throws IllegalStateException.  You don't use nor need 'destination' in either method.  It is useless because the value cannot be changed by the method anyway.   Finally, convertTo(Integer val) should just be { return null != val && val != 0 }.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to map only 0 and 1 to false and true respectively, it is already handled by Dozer out-of-the-box.  If you want to map 0 to false and any other value to true, you need a [custom converter](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/customconverter.html).